# Can I dynamically switch between styles in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, styles

Let's say I wanted to display a `Button` and a few `RadioButtons`. Based on which `RadioButton` is selected, I want to apply a different style to my `Button`. Is this possible in WPF?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Brandon's answer would have worked, but I think this is a little more elegant:

```
<ComboBox Name="AvailableStyles">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Null}" IsSelected="True">None</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{StaticResource FirstStyle}" Style="{StaticResource FirstStyle}">Style 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{StaticResource SecondStyle}" Style="{StaticResource SecondStyle}">Style 2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{StaticResource ThirdStyle}" Style="{StaticResource ThirdStyle}">Style 3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<Button Style="{Binding ElementName=AvailableStyles, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"  Content="Dynamically Styled Button" />
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just set the Style in the code behind.

```
    button.Style = (Style)FindResource("NameOfYourStyle");
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me..the resource is found but nothing happen and the style is not applied.. :/ any advice? thanks