# Dynamically set event handler using DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, datatrigger, eventsetter

iv'e got several itemscontrols which i need to attach an event handler for their 
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event only when a certain condition is met .

iv'e designed a style for my controls with a datatrigger ,i checked out it's bindings and tried it out with a **regular property setter** for the BorderThickness Property just to see that the datatrigger works 
. (It does..)

how can i apply my datatrigger to attach an event handler when the condition of the datatrigger is met using an event setter in the same manner i would a regular property setter ?

something along the lines of :

```
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">                              
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Turn}" Value="True">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ItemsControl_MouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
            </DataTrigger>                            
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

this markup throws the following exception on the eventsetter line :

```
    'Set property 'System.Windows.EventSetter.Event' threw an exception.'
```

Inner Exception :

```
       {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value"}
```

Comment: exactly which line throws that exception? Is it `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Turn}" Value="True">' ?

Comment: @XiaoChuanYu 
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ItemsControl_MouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately according to [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx) under Remarks:

> Note that **only Style.Setters supports EventSetter** objects. Triggers
>   (TriggerBase and derived classes) **do not** support EventSetter

In this case, DataTrigger is derived from TriggerBase so you can't use it to set event handlers dynamically. A workaround I can think of right now might be to dynamically switch styles based on value of `Turn`.

Comment: i actually thought of registering a dependency property , which would 
something like my:mouseleftbuttondown="True" , and use it in a setter 
i don't know if i could use custom dependency property's in a setter ..

Comment: I kinda doubt it fits your situation but you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138339/can-i-dynamically-switch-between-styles-in-wpf

Comment: that's a good idea , ill design a style based on the style i already have and do something like .

<ItemsControl Style="{Binding Turn,Converter={StaticResources MyTurnToStyleConverter}" />

Comment: hmm, how are you going to get a reference to the styles?

Comment: don't really know yet .... i don't have time to deal with it now ,
maybe i could give the Handler value of the eventsetter a binding 
value and set it ether to null or a reference to a handler ,
again i don't know if that's possible ether , i'll post a solution 
when i figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StyleSelector`

```
public sealed class NewItemPlaceholderStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style? Style { get; set; }

    public override Style? SelectStyle(object? item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (NewItemPlaceholder.IsMatch(item))
        {
            return this.Style;
        }

        return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
}
```

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <local:NewItemPlaceholderStyleSelector>
            <local:NewItemPlaceholderStyleSelector.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnMouseDoubleClick" />
                </Style>
            </local:NewItemPlaceholderStyleSelector.Style>
        </local:NewItemPlaceholderStyleSelector>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
```