# How to DataTrigger bind Mouse.Leave command

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<TextBox Text="" x:Name="txtName"/>
      <Button Content="Click">
          <Button.Style>
              <Style TargetType="Button">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=input, Path=Text}" Value="1">
                          <Setter Property="Mouse.Leave" Value="{Binding OnAdd}"></Setter>
                      </DataTrigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=input, Path=Text}" Value="2">
                          <Setter Property="Mouse.Leave" Value="{Binding OnAddMove}"></Setter>
                      </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
          </Button.Style>
      </Button>
```

The Button Click(Property=Command) is work by txtName;
But MouseLeave not work

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673966/dynamically-set-event-handler-using-datatrigger