# What is the best approach With XAML to have elements Displayed on Screen v. Print

Tags: wpf, xaml, printing

With CSS you can target Screen and Print. How would you do this with WPF?

I have elements that I want to display on screen differently than when they are printed.

Right now I'm hacking two instances of the same element, and setting visibility in code, which just feels really really wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: ¿With styles?... or I didn't get your problem.

Comment: Maybe styles is the way to do that, but if it is, I'm not sure how to use them.

Comment: Maybe this is more of a XAML question, than it is a WPF question. But if it matters, I'm in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18388/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-5-Styles), [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/styles/) and [here](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=76368).

Comment: Great links to Styles ... I actually misspoke earlier, I'm already using Styles all over the place. I'm still not sure how to apply styles to elements as they are being printed, and not when they are displayed on the screen. Unless I have to do it programaticaly, in which case that's what I'm already doing. It just feels too hard.

Comment: It turns out 'Style' is a dependency property. Check Pwninstein's solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138339/can-i-dynamically-switch-between-styles-in-wpf (pretty simple and elegant)