# wpf: change the style of a Listview based on the checked radiobutton

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a Listview and a group of radiobutton (two radiobuttons). I would like to change the style of the ListView and the style of the ListViewItem, based on which radiobutton I check. IF possible I would avoid code-behind.

Radiobutton 1 -> ListView displays ListStyle1 and ListViewItem displays ItemStyle1
Radiobutton 2 -> ListView displays ListStyle2 and ListViewItem displays ItemStyle2

I found a similar example using a combobox instead of radiobuttons, but I could not use it in my case because I cannot refer to a "selected item". ( [Can I dynamically switch between styles in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138339/can-i-dynamically-switch-between-styles-in-wpf))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a `DataTrigger` to set your styles based on which `RadioButton` is checked?

```
<Style x:Key="MyListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <!-- Your Style Setters here -->
            <Setter PropertyName="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate1}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <!-- Your Style Setters here -->
            <Setter PropertyName="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate2}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

That said, it's really easy to style a `ListBox` to display as a list of `RadioButtons`. I frequently do this when I want to display a list of items with `RadioButtons`, but still want to maintain the `ListBox` selection behavior.

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="Cycle" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 2, 2, 0" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border Background="Transparent">
                                <RadioButton
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Example use:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyOptions}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}"
         Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonListBoxStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It may seem bad, but I recommend a list (redefining their styles and templates) to simulate the selection of styles.

You can define the organization of the elements, using (or something similar):

```
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StyleName}"/>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

So you just gotta create a custom class for the ItemsSource. In addition to customizing the binding the SelectedValue or SelectedItem.